# Using JS to convert JSON object key : value pairs to summarised JSON of values

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript and currently I have

```
filteredObj = 
    [{Amount: 100, Country: "England"},
    {Amount: 100, Country: "England"},
    {Amount: 200, Country: "England"},
    {Amount: 300, Country: "China"},
    {Amount: 200, Country: "China"},
    {Amount: 100, Country: "England"},
    {Amount: 400, Country: "England"},
    {Amount: 300, Country: "China"}]
```

How can I convert this to

```
   condensedObj =  [{China: 800,
                     England: 900}]
```

The following combines the code but keeps them in separate {}s i.e.

```
 condensedObj = 
[{Country: "China",
  Amount:  800},
  {country: "England",
   Amount: 900}]
```

Current code:

```
condensedObj = filteredObj
    .reduce(
      function (res, obj) {
        if (!(obj['Country'] in res))
          res.__array.push(
            (res[obj['Country'] = obj)
          );
        else {
          res[obj['Country'].Amount +=
            obj.Amount;
        }
        return res;
      },
      { __array: [] }
    )
    .__array.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b.Amount - a.Amount;
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Sorry about that, I have amended the question with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use `.reduce` to create an object with `Country` as `keys` and the sum of `Amount` as `values`
- Then, sort these pairs according to the `value` (Amount) as follows:

```js
const arr = [
  { Amount: 100, Country: "England" },
  { Amount: 100, Country: "England" },
  { Amount: 200, Country: "England" },
  { Amount: 300, Country: "China" },
  { Amount: 200, Country: "China" },
  { Amount: 100, Country: "England" },
  { Amount: 400, Country: "England" },
  { Amount: 300, Country: "China" }
];

const countries = arr.reduce((acc, {Amount,Country}) => 
  ({ ...acc, [Country]: (acc[Country] || 0) + Amount })
, {});
const sorted = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(countries).sort(([,amountA],[,amountB]) => amountA - amountB)
);
const res = [ sorted ];

console.log(res);
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: Best solution, IMO no other Array method will be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - and sorry about not posting code at start. I have amended the question now but don't want to mark as the solution just yet as this solves for the interim steps from my wrongly outputted JSON to the correctly desired JSON which might confuse people.

Comment: @ewldh20 I updated the answer with the new specifications

Comment: Thanks very much - I have marked it as working :)